# Switch/Case with Class Types

Tags: swift, generics

I want to compare class types (SomeClass.self) in a switch statement. Is that possible in Swift, e.g.

```
func retrieveData<T>(forType: T.Type, _ completion: @escaping (Decodable?, Error?) -> Void)
{
    switch forType
    {
        case JonModel.self:
            getJonData(completion)
        case JaneModel.self:
            getJaneData(completion)
    }
}
```

This however produces an error:
`Expression pattern of type 'JonModel.Type' cannot match values of type 'T.Type'`.

Can this be done? I could of course define an enum just for all my data model types but I'm wondering if this can be done just by comparing given data model types.

Comment: The referenced Q&A should answer your question, otherwise let me know and I'll reopen the question.

Comment: THX! The above link solved it!